# show div on scroll - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I cant seem to find the answer for the following problem.

I need to be able to scroll down a page and show a specific div when scrolled over. the divs will then remain there.

I have created the html but cant figure out the jquery.

The first div needs to remain there, and the 2nd and 3rd hidden until scrolled on.

Can anybody help?

```
<div class="content1">content 1</div>
<div class="content2">content 2</div>
<div class="content3">content 3</div>


.content1 {
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
.content2 {
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
.content3 {
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid orange;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Hb/6/

thank you !

Comment: So which div exactly must appear on scroll?

Comment: Please be more specific on your explaination

Comment: 2nd and 3rd div to be shown on scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Sachin's answer...

You could then do

```
$('.content1').fadeIn('slow');
```

See the following

http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Hb/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event to catch this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   // now on the basis of scrollTop value show your div
     if(scrollTop > 200){
      // show div1
     }
     // and so on
    })
})
```

Comment: hi, i just updated the fiddle. can you check it out and amend where needed?? thanks for your help ! http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Hb/6/